# How Do I Set the Background Color of buttons including a Checkbox button?

Tags: c++, winapi, button, mfc, transparent

**How Do I Set the Background Color of buttons including a Checkbox button?**

I struggled to find the answer to this today - thinking it should be simple to answer this, but the information I stumbled on was less than helpful, so at the risk of duplicating stuff that's out there but I couldn't find, I'll make this quick'n'dirty how-to...

Comment: You can also use classes like CMFCButton that have a OnFillBackground event handler. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb983153.aspx

Comment: Thanks!  Good to know.  In my case I was using standard winapi 'button' windows (controls).  So not an issue.  But those add yet another wrinkle to that scenario which is great to beware of!

Comment: It's important to know that all of the CMFCxxx classes are actually wrappers for shell common controls - and not for the legacy standard window controls such as 'Button' - for the newer shell based controls - different rules apply.

Answer (score 3):

All 'Button' class windows send `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` to their parent window, which can then call `::SetBkColor((HDC)wParam, rgbBkColor)`, and return a brush for that color.

If this is all using system colors, then the brush handle doesn't need to be managed, you can simply ask for the `::GetSysColor(sysIndex)`, and return the `::GetSysColorBrush(sysIndex)` for the returned brush.

If you're using a custom color, then you'll need to create your own brush and manage the handle for that.

I needed this code for a Message Box replacement, which has the upper part using a white background, and the lower part using a gray background, per the Windows standard message box.  So my static control (icon) needed to be white, while my other buttons (including a "Don't ask again" checkbox) needed to have a gray background (checkboxes normally have a white background).

So, I handle WM_ERASEBKGND to paint the two portions of the background correctly, and then I handle WM_CLTLCOLORSTATIC to ensure that all buttons are properly "transparent" for the background that they appear on.  In my case, the I used a "Static" control for the icon, which draws its background in gray, and a couple of push-buttons plus a checkbox button - which a checkbox button always paints its background in white, so both required a fix.

My example is using MFC, but hopefully you can translate that trivially enough for your purposes:

```
// add to the message map:

    ON_MESSAGE(WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC, OnCtlColorStatic)

// create the implementation:

LRESULT CRTFMessageBox::OnCtlColorStatic(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    // buttons and static controls (icon) send WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC, so we can force them to use the correct background color here...
    const HDC hdc = (HDC)wParam;
    const int idc = ::GetDlgCtrlID((HWND)lParam);

    // choose a system color or brush based on if this is icon (static) or another control (a button)
    const int idx = idc == IDC_STATIC ? COLOR_WINDOW : COLOR_3DFACE;

    // select system color
    ::SetBkColor(hdc, GetSysColor(idx));

    // return system brush (which we don't need to delete!)
    return (LRESULT)GetSysColorBrush(idx);
}
```